# Selenium Webdriver - SessionNotCreatedError

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting this error:

> SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000

I am running protractor tests on Windows 8 Chrome. What happens is that a  Chrome tab will open but won't load the url, and will open
`C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` shell window. Then nothing else happens and the test times out. Which makes sense that I get a timeout error. **But I'm not sure why it isn't loading the website in the first place.**

When I close the chrome tab I then get this message:

> SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception from tab crashed`

I am up to date on both selenium standalone and chromedriver. The only thing I can think of is that Chrome was recently updated to 46.0.2490.71, *but I don't have any problems on Windows 7 with this same version.*

What is the issue here??

Here's the full log:

```
/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113
var template = new Error(this.message);
             ^
SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception 
from tab crashed
(Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.71)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243     (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30.24 seconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'Win8Test', ip: '192.168.1.185', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
at new bot.Error     (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113:18)
at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:106:9)
at /Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:158:24
at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1877:20)
at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:2464:25)
at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:563:12)
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.goog.array.forEach (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/array/array.js:203:43)
at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:552:16)
at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:125:21)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:155:22)
at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:129:30)
at [object Object].Builder.build (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:416:22)
at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:38:7)
at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:180:37)
at /Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:256:21
at _fulfilled (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
at /Users/awilliamson/projects/chewie/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1`
```

**Edit**: I am using `"protractor": "^2.5.1"` and `"jasmine": "^2.3.2"`

Comment: Try downgrade one or two versions of Google Chrome and test it on windows 8. If works, maybe you will need find and implement some argument when you create the instance of Chrome Driver.

Comment: i tried downloading an old chrome version but it made me update to 46

Comment: My team have the same issue on Appveyor, the versions of `selenium-server-standalone` (2.45.0) and `chromedriver` (2.15) haven't changed so it makes me wonder if it's to do with the recent [Chrome update to v46](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/stable-channel-update.html). Not sure how to downgrade it though.

Comment: Updating `protractor` to a version greater than `2.2.0` fixed it for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading Chromedriver 2.19 is what I needed to do. I was using 2.16 and  for some reason `webdriver-manager update --chromedriver` wasn't working and said I had the latest version. But apparently not. Thank you @jjj!!

Answer (score 4):

I am getting this same identical error please see below for my solution.

Checked in code yesterday, everything ran fine. Fired up a suite this morning and saw exact behavior cocoa is seeing.

Chrome/chromedriver are up to date. Protractor is v2.2 (working on upgrade), Jasmine v2x. Webdriver-manager update shows everything is cool. JDK up to date. The only thing I'm still chasing are the Jasmine-reporters, of which I am using v2x.

EDIT:
I just resolved by:

- Updating node.js from the msi file (located here: https://nodejs.org/en/)
- Running the webmanager update (webdriver-manager update) which pulled down the latest selenium jar and chomedriver.exe
- I then ran a test that was failing this morning and it ran successfully, no errors.

Comment: glad to see i'm not the only one with this issue. unfortunately that didn't work for me :(

Comment: i have this issue too, and didn't work for me, any another solution :(

Comment: Had this same issue on our grid nodes. Could see Chrome launching but hanging forever loading the `data` url on launch. Upgraded Chromedriver to 2.19 on all the nodes (they were using 2.16) and they are working fine now.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Linux system with chromedriver=2.21

Answer (score 1):

You may need to upgrade `chromedriver`. On Mac, this should be as easy as `brew upgrade chromedriver`. Otherwise, you can [download the latest version](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and place it in the correct folder for your particular setup.

Answer (score -1):

Download chrome browser from website http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
And save it on the C:\Downloads\chromedriver_win32

use below syntax to start and initialize chrome driver 
driverGC = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Downloads\chromedriver_win32");